# PyroCMS altering tags after saving page

Tags: html, fancybox, pyrocms

I'm having a few issues with PyroCMS altering some of my tags after I save the page. I feel like the altering may be because of a grammatical error but I'm not sure what it could be.

My aim is to render each photo inside a folder, and wrap each image in a link to it's full size image so that I can use [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net) to view the full-size images inline.

Here is my code:

```
{{ files:listing folder="4" }}
    <a class="fancy" href="{{ files:image_path id="{{ id }}" }}">
        <img alt="{{ description }}" src="{{ url:site }}files/large/{{ id }}" />
    </a>
{{ /files:listing }}
```

And after saving the page it gets changed to this:

```
{{ files:listing folder="4" }}
&lt;a class="fancy" data-cke-saved-href="{{ files:image_path id=" href="{{ files:image_path id=" {{="" id="" }}"=""&gt;
<img alt="{{ description }}" src="{{ url:site }}files/large/{{ id }}" /> {{ /files:listing }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that if I change the page editor to HTML not WYSIWYG then there are no parsing errors and the page renders fine and no changes are made after saving the page.